# Create a Non-Database-Driven Lookup

Tags: containers, lookup, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

Lots of references for creating lookups out there, but all seem to draw their values from a query.

I want to add a lookup to a field that will add items from a list of values that do not come from a table, query, or any other data source.

Such as from a string: "Bananas, Apples, Oranges"
..or a container ["Bananas", "Apples", "Oranges"]

Assume the string/container is a dynamic object.  Drawing from an static enum is not a choice.

Is there a way to create lookups on the fly from something other than a data source?

Example code would be a great help, but I'll take hints as well.

Comment: Sometimes, you have to do a cost-benefit analysis to determine if it's worth the trouble.  I do believe there is a way to do this--the old sysLookup method from AX2009 supported creating lists on the fly.  I suspect one could just import the old method if they were so inclined.  I, however, just put my data into a table.  I don't have time to fight with this any more.

Comment: Fortunately tables are easy to create in AX. Probably that is why there is more than 4000. No code needed!

Comment: However, in the interest of the community, I think we should consider continuing this discussion to either a conclusion of either "this is impossible" or a working code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't the most graceful solution, but this does work, and it doesn't override or modify any native AX 2012 objects:

```
Copy the sysLookup form from AX2009 (rename it) and import it into AX 2012.     
We'll call mine myLookupFormCopy.
I did a find/replace of "sysLookup" in the XPO file to rename it.
```

Create this class method:

```
public static client void lookupList(FormStringControl _formStringControl, List _valueList, str _columnLabel = '')
{
Args    args;
FormRun formRun;
;

if (_formStringControl && _valueList && _valueList.typeId() == Types::String)
{
    args = new Args(formstr(myLookupFormCopy));
    args.parmObject(_valueList);
    args.parm(_columnLabel);
    formRun = classFactory.formRunClass(args);
    _formStringControl.performFormLookup(formRun);
}
}
```

In the lookup method for your string control, use:

```
public void lookup()
{
List    valueList = new List(Types::String);
;

...build your valueList here...

MyClass::lookupList(this, valueList, "List Title");

super();
}
```

Comment: You could use `global::pickList` instead if you could accept that it sorts by the key. This is really a bad name! `picMap` would way better!

Comment: Modified the post to make explain that better.  That refers to the name of the copy of the sysLookup form you created in step one.

Answer (score 2):

There is the [color picker](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Color_picker).

Also in the `Global` you will find `pickXxxx` such as [pickList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/global.picklist.aspx).
There are others, `pickUser`, `pickUserGroup` etc.

Take a look on the implementation. I guess they build a temporary table then displays that. Tables are great!

Update:

To go on you own [follow the rules](http://www.axaptapedia.com/index.php?title=Lookup_Form).

For the advanced user, see also: [Lookup form returning more than one value](http://kashperuk.blogspot.com/2010_01_01_archive.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
public void lookup()
{
    SysTableLookup                  sysTableLookup;
    TmpTableFieldLookup             tmpTableFieldLookup; 
    Enumerator                      en;    
    List                            entitylist      = new list(types::String);

    entitylist.addend("Banana");
    entitylist.addend("Apple");

    en = entityList.getEnumerator();

    while (en.moveNext())
    {
        tmpTableFieldLookup.TableName = en.current();               
        tmpTableFieldLookup.insert();
    }

    sysTableLookup = SysTableLookup::newParameters(tableNum(tmpTableFieldLookup), this);

    sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(TmpTableFieldLookup, TableName));

    //BP Deviation documented
    sysTableLookup.parmTmpBuffer(tmpTableFieldLookup);
    sysTableLookup.performFormLookup();
}
```

The above code helps in displaying strings as lookup.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also guessing there's no way to perform a lookup without a table. I say that because a lookup is simply a form with one or more datasources that is displayed in a different way.

I've also blogged about this, so you can get some info on how to perform a lookup, even with a temporary table, here:

http://devexpp.blogspot.com.br/2012/02/dynamics-ax-custom-lookup.html

Comment: You are guessing wrong, you only have to specify the the returning control in the `selectMode` method. This control may event be invisible.

Comment: @JanB.Kjeldsen So you're saying we can actually perform a lookup without a table or even a temporary table?

Comment: Yes, you can also call `closeSelect` with anything you want to return. Calling method `selectMode` from the `init` is the usual ting to do, as most return values come from a control in the lookup form.

Comment: Wait, you're telling me that the _form_ doesn't have to have a datasource, but we _do_ need table to perform the datasource. That means, to populate the little form that pops up, right?

Comment: A form need not have a datasource, if it does not have a grid. For example if you presents primes from 2 to 100 in individual controls, you need neither datasource nor a grid. You can then `closeSelect` any value clicked.

Comment: @JanB.Kjeldsen Yes but that's exaclty what we're talking about, exactly what he wants. He wants a form with a grid, a lookup. The point is: you're saying that you _can_ perform a lookup without a table?

Comment: Yes, is it possible. I think `pickList` most closely match what he wants.

Comment: @JanB.Kjeldsen Even after looking at the link you provided in your answer I still have it in my mind that you can't perform a lookup without having a table to fetch the records from, so I'm keeping my answer as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Example from global::PickEnumValue:

```cs
static int pickEnumValue(EnumId _enumId, boolean _omitZero = false)
{
    Object      formRun;
    container   names;
    container   values;
    int         i,value = -1,valueIndex;
    str         name;
    #ResAppl
    DictEnum dictEnum = new DictEnum(_enumId);
    ;
    if (!dictEnum)
        return -1;


    for (i=1;i<=dictEnum.values();i++)
    {
        value = dictEnum.index2Value(i);
        if (!(_omitZero && (value == 0)))
        {
            names += dictEnum.index2Label(i);
            values += value;
        }
    }
    formRun = classfactory.createPicklist();
    formRun.init();
    formRun.choices(names, #ImageClass);
    formRun.caption(dictEnum.label());
    formRun.run();
    formRun.wait();
    name = formRun.choice();
    value = formRun.choiceInt();
    if (value>=0) // the picklist form returns -1 if a choice has not been made
    {
        valueIndex = -1;
        for (i=1;i<=conLen(names);i++)
        {
            if (name == conPeek(names,i))
            {
                valueIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (valueIndex>=0)
            return conPeek(values,valueIndex);
    }


    return value;
}
```